# LaTex in Matplotlib yields error "Sorry, but C:#\bin\latex.exe did not succeed"

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, miktex

I want to use LaTex in my matplotlib.pyplot plots for my thesis, but struggle to get it going. I have installed MikTex from the official page and get use the following code.

```
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)

def f(t):
    return t ** 2

t1 = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.1)

noise = np.random.randn(len(t1)) * 0.04


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 3), dpi=200)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.scatter(t1, f(t1 + noise), facecolors='none', label='Values obtained by experiment', edgecolors='k')
plt.plot(t1, f(t1), ls='solid', label='Theoretical expectation', color='k')
plt.legend()
```

Now, if I run this command, a window named "Package Installation" opens: The required file "tex\latex\type1cm\type1cm.sty" is missing. The package will be installed from : Random package repository

Now, after I press install, I get:

```
RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'lp'

Here is the full report generated by latex:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6730)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/Leo/.matplotlib/tex.cache/d97ff769cca1b07656427b11e7187cec.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\size10.clo))

Sorry, but C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\latex.exe did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/Leo/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/latex.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
```

the latex.log file says

```
2021-01-30 19:40:11,457+0100 INFO  latex - starting with command line: C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\latex.exe
2021-01-30 19:40:11,467+0100 INFO  latex - allowing known shell commands
2021-01-30 19:40:11,467+0100 INFO  latex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2021-01-30 19:43:47,029+0100 INFO  latex - starting with command line: C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\latex.exe -interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error C:\Users\Leo\.matplotlib\tex.cache\d97ff769cca1b07656427b11e7187cec.tex
2021-01-30 19:43:47,035+0100 INFO  latex - allowing known shell commands
2021-01-30 19:43:47,035+0100 INFO  latex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2021-01-30 19:45:27,837+0100 INFO  latex - installing package type1cm triggered by tex\latex\type1cm\type1cm.sty
2021-01-30 19:45:27,837+0100 FATAL latex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2021-01-30 19:45:27,837+0100 FATAL latex - Info: 
2021-01-30 19:45:27,837+0100 FATAL latex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2021-01-30 19:45:27,837+0100 FATAL latex - Line: 1270
2021-01-30 19:45:27,839+0100 INFO  latex - finishing with exit code 1
```

Comment: What does `C:/Users/Leo/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/latex.log` say?

Comment: Thats the point, I cannot find the folder AppData under C:/Users/Leo. There is, however, a folder at C:/Users/family, where the latex.log says:

Comment: You have problematic `latex` installation. Because your code runs perfectly fine. Also your `AppData` folder is hidden, this will [help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-10-97fbc472-c603-9d90-91d0-1166d1d9f4b5#:~:text=Open%20File%20Explorer%20from%20the,folders%2C%20and%20drives%20and%20OK.).

Comment: What do you use to run the code ?

Comment: I use spyder, but I guess latex is the problem. It is weird that MikTex is installed under ```C:Users/Family```, could that be a problem?

Comment: I don't think `spyder` handle latex well. I would recommend `jupyter notebook`. Let me know if that didn't work.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have added the latex.log file to the original post.

Comment: @LionCereals Can you try to open the miktex package manager and try to install `type1cm` from there? There seems to be something strange going on with admin/user mode stuff (on of the reasons I very much prefer texlive over miktex)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Did it, but still get the same error message. Is there maybe an alternative option to work with?

Comment: try with [texlive](https://tug.org/texlive/windows.html) and see if that works.